# Why does the "m" key disable my text editor?

Tags: keyboard

Sometimes, it's the "o" key, but lately it's been the "m" key.

When I hit the "m" key, either by typing a message letter by letter or using Swype, my editing stops. I cannot recover without closing my editor and getting back in. Sometimes, I have to completely reboot my phone, and that seems to help. When I get back into the message to try again, I can edit until I hit the "m" key again.

Comment: Which app is this?

Answer (score 0):

Some phones allow the user to assign single key presses as accelerators to start applications, dial regular contacts, or the like. Is it possible you set something like this? Check your keyboard settings for a keyboard type you may not use regularly. I think I remember this was a possible setting on the Galaxy Stratosphere, or similar.
UPDATE: The Stratosphere has this setting under Applications\QuickLaunch. It can accept a combo key press to start any application at users discretion. Maybe you have 'm' or 'o' set somehow similar.